# Is there any package for LaTeX dealing with a database?

Tags: packages, database

Is there any package for LaTeX dealing with a database (with some of the fields being  LaTeX code). For example, given a collection of problems with fields {id, name, author, refs, statement, solution, difficulty, keywords...} the package should allow to build a latex document from the data filtering by any of the fields (obtaining, for example, a list of the "easy" algebra problems with authors but without solutions). Another possible application is a multilingual CV being the fields the CV entries and the rows the data in the corresponding language.

I managed to simulate this scheme using .bib files to store the data, but as some drawbacks appeared (relative to the code interpretation) I just wonder if there is something specifically designed for this situations.

Comment: There is the [`datatool`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package. I haven't used it myself so I can't say more about it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @cgnieder I've used the `datatool` package and I'm happy to recommend it.

Comment: If you really want a database then this question is relevant: [Reading data from a relational database into a LaTeX table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48193/2693). If your needs are more modest, then [pgfplotstable or datatool?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44105/2693) might be more relevant.

Comment: See also the blog post [LaTeX and template engines, revisited](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/latex-and-template-engines-revisited/).

Comment: If you want to build exames from already defined exercises tagged with some words, [Exsheets](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets) can help you. Look at Exsheets' author answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83942/1952).

Comment: I frequently use [template toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/). Works with all data sources supported by Perl's database interface.

Comment: Thank you all, I probably will give datatool a try (since it seems that it can convert my .bib files) before going into something more involved.

Comment: You can use also `textmerg`, there an example in [build dynamic documents from a Textdatabase](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70949/build-dynamic-documents-from-a-textdatabase).

Comment: @suitangi, If you mean accessing database to create tables, I use R, which has good connectivity via RODBC. You can then, of course, create the tables directly (in LaTeX format) via use of R xtable package. The above, used in conjunction with knitr means that data frames (and other data objects) in R can be ported DIRECTLY into LaTeX document, facilitating real-time, data-driven, up-to-date documentation to your liking. Might seem convaluted, but its really quite straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

*Excerpt from comments below question:*

If you really want a database then this question is relevant: [Reading data from a relational database into a LaTeX table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48193/reading-data-from-a-relational-database-into-a-latex-table). If your needs are more modest, then [pgfplotstable or datatool?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44105/pgfplotstable-or-datatool) might be more relevant. See also the post in our TeX community blog: [LaTeX and template engines, revisited](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/latex-and-template-engines-revisited/). You can use also `textmerg`, there is an example in [build dynamic documents from a Textdatabase](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70949/build-dynamic-documents-from-a-textdatabase).

Perhaps also some TeX external solutions fit your needs: [Template Toolkit](http://www.template-toolkit.org/) (works with all data sources supported by Perl's database interface); R with knitr (create the tables directly in LaTeX format via use of R xtable package, and in conjunction with knitr port data frames and other data objects in R DIRECTLY into a LaTeX document).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [datatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331594/using-an-exercises-package-to-build-lots-of-math-calculus-exercise-lists-and-tes/332025#332025). I think that it has the functionality you need.